# Set confidence score threshold in localize_objects function to get all of the results

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm using localize_objects function, which returns bounding boxes with labels and confidence scores. For my image localize_objects returns 6 detected objects. But when I'm using this same image in google cloud product search function, it returns groupped_results, with similar products attached to detected objects, and there there are 8 detected objects.
I think the problem is that localize_objects returns objects which confidence scores are higher than certain value(say 0.5), how can I make this threshold lower, and get all of the objects.

objects = client.object_localization(
image=image, max_results=50).localized_object_annotations

I tried to find a parameter to pass to this method, but ChatGPT's and Bard's results were wrong or outdated.